# How to find memory usage of web applications in apache tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, memory-management, web-applications

I'm working on a project where I need to find the memory usage of web applications deployed in Apache tomcat. In an intranet architecture i'd like to develop a tool to find the users accessing the deployed web application and its memory being used. Could someone help me start off with this project. I have configured Apache tomcat and deployed few web applications now. Performance monitoring is the objective of my project.
Thank You.

Comment: So, did you find an answer to your question by any chance?

Answer (score 7):

You can access the memory usage for the Tomcat JVM using JMX pretty easy. See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206002/how-to-get-memory-usage-of-tomcat-7-using-jmx-api) for more info. Please note that you will get memory usage for tomcat + all deployed web apps. You cannot get memory usage for a single webapp, since Tomcat share a single java process for both container and apps. If you want better control over memory usage per app, I suggest you either use a more sophisticated application server or use a tomcat instance per webapp.

To monitor connected users, I guess you have to do something on the application layer. Tomcat is not really aware of the concept of "user", since that is typically something you implement in the code (like Spring Security).

Answer (score 4):

Did you read this? You can't, please read [http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory (archive.org copy)](http://web.archive.org/web/20150127044223/http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Memory) too:

> You can't find out how much memory a web application is using. The JVM doesn't give us these detail or information.

Comment: Is it possible to monitor performance ?? That is the main objective of my project.

Comment: Yes you can, there are external tools available that will help you.. You could try a search on google for a tool and you'll be able to pick the one you like. The following link could be helpful to you as well [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-monitor-and-manage-apache-tomcat) I hope this comment will bring you into the right direction

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [glowroot](https://glowroot.org/) a very good open source Java application performance monitoring (APM) tool that you can attach to Tomcat without change any java source code.

To use it just need [download](https://github.com/glowroot/glowroot/releases/download/v0.10.12/glowroot-0.10.12-dist.zip) it and add on the start of your JVM
`-javaagent:path/to/glowroot.jar`

For tomcat you need to add the environment variable

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:path/to/glowroot.jar"`
on `/etc/tomcat8/tomcat8.conf`

For more details see instructions on project [github](https://github.com/glowroot/glowroot/wiki/Where-are-my-application-server's-JVM-args%3F#tomcat-8-linux)

It has very light [overhead](https://glowroot.org/overhead.html) that you could use temporary in production to extract several application performance information and tested with Tomcat.

You can see a demo of gauges from JVM and [histogram](https://demo.glowroot.org/jvm/heap-histogram) of the heap memory [here](https://demo.glowroot.org/jvm/gauges?gauge-name=java.lang:type%3DMemory:HeapMemoryUsage.used)

Comment: This is a great tool. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Pinpoint, glowroot,java melody,visualVM(comes with JDK), Java mission control(comes with JDK) can help you to understand heap utilization and other performance parameters (like thrade utilization, response time, bottlenecks etc..)
My favorite is Glowroot.. :) It's easy to install and provide really good insight of application.
Demo Url 
Glowroot: https://demo.glowroot.org/transaction/average?transaction-type=Web
Java melody:http://javamelody.org/demo/monitoring
I hope this help you :)