# How to check memory size of each web application in single tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications, tomcat8

In my tomcat have more than one web application is running.how to know that each application memory usage and status?

Comment: In tomcat you can use psi-probe: https://github.com/psi-probe/psi-probe

Answer (score 1):

More that one applications running on same Tomcat share the same JVM. Hence its not possible to monitor the usage by each app. Refer to the following similar answer :
[How to find memory usage of web applications in apache tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885579/how-to-find-memory-usage-of-web-applications-in-apache-tomcat)